# How to migrate a table which contains a JSON column from AWS RedShift to BigQuery in Python?

Tags: python, sql, json, google-bigquery, data-migration

I want to migrate the data tables from AWS database to BigQuery. I have a specific table named sampletable which includes id, user_id and log. Log is a JSON field that contains a dictionary which consists of keys and its respective values.

```
'reason': {
    'id': 5,
    'name': 'Sample name'
    'contact':  {
        number = 123
        address = None
     }
},
'subreason': {
    'id': 80,
    'name': 'Sample name',
    'is_active': True,
    'created_at': '2022-07-18T18:33:28.911Z',
    'deleted_at': None,
    'complaint_id': 5,
},
```

This is the function that loads the data from the table to BigQuery:

```
def load_data(table_id, data):
    print("load_data::Writing records to table", table_id)
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
        schema=[
            bigquery.SchemaField("id", "INT64"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("user_id", "INT64"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("log", "JSON"),
        ],
    )
    try:
        start = time.time()
        job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
            data, table_id, job_config=job_config
        )
        job.result()
        end = time.time()
        print("load_data::Time taken for writing " + str(data.shape[0]) + " records: ", end - start, "s")
    except Exception as e:
        print("load_data::exception", e)
        print("load_data::Could not establish connection with Google BigQuery. Terminating program")
        conn.close()
        sys.exit()
```

However, an exception arises. The exception is that "exception cannot mix list and non-list, non-null values".

I tried changing the schema in this way:

```
        schema=[
            bigquery.SchemaField("id", "INT64"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("user_id", "INT64"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("log", "RECORD"), fields=
            [
                bigquery.SchemaField("reason", "RECORD", fields=
                [
                    bigquery.SchemaField("id", "INT64"),
                    bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING")
                    bigquery.SchemaField("contact", "RECORD", fields=
                    [
                    bigquery.SchemaField("number", "STRING")
                    bigquery.SchemaField("address," "STRING"))
                    ]
                ]),
bigquery.SchemaField("subreason", "RECORD", fields=
                [
                    bigquery.SchemaField("id", "INT64"),
                    bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING")
                    bigquery.SchemaField("is_active", "BOOLEAN")
                    bigquery.SchemaField("created_at", "TIMESTAMP")
                    bigquery.SchemaField("deleted_at", "TIMESTAMP")
                    bigquery.SchemaField("complaint_id", "INT64")
                ]),
            ])
```

However, I get the exception " with type dict: was expecting tuple of (key, value) pair "
Can anyone guide me in this issue as I am new to data migration of JSON columns in tables? What is the proper way to modify the schema to accept the JSON columns for migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and consider below approach.

In this approach, you will be loading the data as `JSON` data type in **BigQuery**. However, there will be manual adjustment on the JSON file since BigQuery accepts **new-line delimited JSON** for data ingestion. See below sample updated file json file.

```json
{"log":{"reason":{"contact":{"address": null,"number": 123},"id": 5,"name": "Sample name"},"subreason": {"complaint_id": 5,"created_at": "2022-07-18T18:33:28.911Z","deleted_at": "None","id": 80,"is_active": true,"name": "Sample name"}}}
```

Notice that I compressed the JSON into one key which is named `"log"` and also compressed it into one line to satisfy **new-line delimited JSON**.

**Below is the python code I used to ingest the data:**

```py
table_id = "your-project.-your-dataset.your-table"
file_path = "/path/of/your_json_file.json"


def load_table_file(file_path, table_id):

    # [START bigquery_load_from_file]
    from google.cloud import bigquery

    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    client = bigquery.Client()

    # TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
    

    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON, autodetect=True,
        #write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
        schema=[
            bigquery.SchemaField("log", "JSON"),
        ],
    )

    with open(file_path, "rb") as source_file:
        job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_id, job_config=job_config)

    job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

    table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
    print(
        "Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(
            table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id
        )
    )
    # [END bigquery_load_from_file]
    return table

load_table_file(file_path, table_id)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: You are importing a separate JSON file right? I don't have a JSON file. The table has the JSON column. The filepath is not needed in this scenario as our JSON field is in a table in postgres, and I need to ingest the whole table into BigQuery database.

Comment: It would be the same approach. Instead of updating a  JSON file like I mentioned, you need to update the actual JSON on your code which is inside your `data` parameter (called in load_data())